# How to speedup my table conversion algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a task to convert string tables from one format to another.
[image]

I use this class to convert table:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class TableConverter
{
    public String[] Entities; //here I store descriptive fields like DescField1, DescField2...
    public ArrayList<String> ConvertedList; //here I store converted table rows as separate string lines 

    public TableConverter(ArrayList<String> lines) //we receive table rows as separate string lines
    {
        String[] splitted_first_line = lines.get(0).split("\t"); //split first row to get descriptive fields
        this.Entities = new String[splitted_first_line.length - 2]; //allocate size to hold all descriptive fields. -2 because last two columns is Date and Total
        System.arraycopy(splitted_first_line, 0, this.Entities, 0, this.Entities.length); //copy descriptive fields into my arr     

        //--

        int lines_sz = lines.size(); //save lines size to not recalculate it every iteration 
        Map<String, Integer> k_d_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //map to store indecies of every Date column

        for (int i = 1; i < lines_sz; i++)
        {
            if (lines.get(i).isEmpty())
                continue;

            String[] splitted_line = lines.get(i).split("\t"); //splitted line on values    

            if (!k_d_map.containsKey(splitted_line[splitted_line.length - 2])) //if my map does not contain such date
                k_d_map.put(splitted_line[splitted_line.length - 2], 0); //then add it
        }

        String[] known_dates = k_d_map.keySet().toArray(new String[k_d_map.size()]);
        SortStrDates(known_dates); //I sort dates by ASC 
        k_d_map.clear(); //clear map to fill it again with correct indecies

        for (int i = 0; i < known_dates.length; i++) //refilling map and now we know every date index
            k_d_map.put(known_dates[i], i);

        //--

        Map<String, EntitySales> ESs_map = new HashMap<String, EntitySales>(); //map for rows

        for (int i = 1; i < lines_sz; i++)
        {
            if (lines.get(i).isEmpty())
                continue;

            String[] splitted_line = lines.get(i).split("\t"); //split row  
            String curr_entity = GetEntityFromLine(splitted_line); //I get set of descriptive fields separated by \t. It looks like this: asd\tqwe\t...\tzxc
            int dti = k_d_map.get(splitted_line[splitted_line.length - 2]); //I get date column index for Date stored in this row (if it was 02.2017 then index will be 0) 

            if (ESs_map.containsKey(curr_entity)) //I check if map contains row with such descriptive fields set
                ESs_map.get(curr_entity).SalesAmounts[dti] = splitted_line[splitted_line.length - 1]; //if contains, we set sale amount at date index (set 5 to 02.2017 column for example)
            else
            {
                EntitySales es = new EntitySales(curr_entity, known_dates.length); //else we create new object to hold row          
                es.SalesAmounts[dti] = splitted_line[splitted_line.length - 1]; //set sales amount at date
                ESs_map.put(curr_entity, es); //and add to map
            }
        }

        //--

        String first_row = ""; //here and below I build first row text representation, I add stored DescFields and unique dates
        this.ConvertedList = new ArrayList<String>();               

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Entities.length; i++)
            first_row += this.Entities[i] + "\t";

        for (int i = 0; i < known_dates.length; i++)
            first_row += i < known_dates.length - 1 ? known_dates[i] + "\t" : known_dates[i];

        this.ConvertedList.add(first_row);

        //--

        for (EntitySales es : ESs_map.values()) //Here I get rows as separate lines 
            this.ConvertedList.add(es.GetAsLine());
    }

    public String GetEntityFromLine(String[] line)
    {
        String[] entities = new String[line.length - 2];
        System.arraycopy(line, 0, entities, 0, entities.length);

        String entity = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < entities.length; i++)
            entity += i < entities.length - 1 ? entities[i] + "\t" : entities[i];

        return entity;
    }

    public void SortStrDates(String[] dates)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < dates.length; j++)
            {
                Date dt_i = MyJunk.ConvertStrToDate(dates[i]);
                Date dt_j = MyJunk.ConvertStrToDate(dates[j]);

                if (dt_j.before(dt_i))
                {
                    String temp_i = dates[i];
                    dates[i] = dates[j];
                    dates[j] = temp_i;
                }
            }
    }
}

class EntitySales
{
    public String Entity;
    public String[] SalesAmounts;

    public EntitySales(String entity, int sales_amounts_size)
    {
        this.Entity = entity;
        this.SalesAmounts = new String[sales_amounts_size];
    }

    public String GetAsLine()
    {
        String line = this.Entity + "\t";

        for (int i = 0; i < this.SalesAmounts.length; i++)
        {
            String val = this.SalesAmounts[i] == null || this.SalesAmounts[i].isEmpty() ? "0" : this.SalesAmounts[i];
            line += i < this.SalesAmounts.length - 1 ? val + "\t" : val;
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```

It works, but it ultimate slow with huge tables.
I waited for 1 hour and 20 minutes to convert 800k rows table and cancelled task.
200k rows gets converted just in 3 minutes. I don't know why I got such slowdown, but the question is how to speedup my algorithm a lot?
I tried to assign `Integer` values to every set of descriptive fields (asd\tqwe\t...\tzxc -> 0, something\telse -> 1) and compare that integers without `Maps`, but it was only slower.

Comment: Small improvement: do not declare Strings and String arrays inside your for loops. For example you can delcare `String[] splitted_line`only once in your TableConverter method and use it in the 2 for loops.

Comment: @StephaneM - got it, thank you, sadly I don't think it will speedup everything too much.

Comment: It might help you understand where the time is spent to run the code under the supervision of a profiler.

Comment: Another bigger improvement: use a faster sort algorithm. Your bubble sort is ok if you know you have small arays because it's easy and fast to code. But with your big arrays consider using another algorithm such as a quicksort.

Comment: @StephaneM - I know there is small arrays... And sorting done only once per table. For example if table contains all months in one year, then there are only 12 dates to sort. 365 for days is also fine enough. The problem somewhere else...

Comment: You should rethink your code: 1) Simplify it, you have to many for(..){}. 2) Don't create objects inside a for, always create them outside an reuse them .3)Don't copy the array, just lower your for by 2, you are again cycling the array. You have read the table 5 times by the end of your code.. 4)Look up the stream API and use the filter method, much faster than what you have coded. 5) Don't use a map for what you are doing use a list, and do not call contains, you are cycling the map again and the again to get the value. 6) Use java naming convention, so its easy to help you next time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whereas you could improve your overall algorithm, the primary slowdown is probably in your `GetAsLine` function:

```
public String GetAsLine()
{
    String line = this.Entity + "\t";

    for (int i = 0; i < this.SalesAmounts.length; i++)
    {
        String val = this.SalesAmounts[i] == null || this.SalesAmounts[i].isEmpty() ? "0" : this.SalesAmounts[i];
        line += i < this.SalesAmounts.length - 1 ? val + "\t" : val;
    }

    return line;
}
```

Here, you're using string concatenation in a loop to build your key. This is highly inefficient because it allocates a new string every time through the loop. That involves allocating memory for the new string and copying the existing string to the new string. Your garbage collector get lots of exercise.

To improve this, what you want to do is create a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and construct the string in there:

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < this.SalesAmounts.length; i++)
{
    String val = this.SalesAmounts[i] == null || this.SalesAmounts[i].isEmpty() ? "0" : this.SalesAmounts[i];
    line.append(val+"\t");
}
// remove final tab character
line.remove(line.length()-1, line.length()-1);

return line.toString();
```

The reason this is faster is because `StringBuilder` doesn't create a new string every time you append something. So you do a whole lot less copying of strings.